# copy texture to another texture use glcopyteximage2d

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I use the frame buffer to draw the graphics to the texture, and then I want to copy the content of this texture to another texture. These two textures were created in different gl contexts.

There is a method that works, but the performance is relatively poor. First use glReadPixels to read the data from the frame buffer, then de-premultiply (because the data in the frame buffer is pre-multiplied), and then use glTexImage2D to transfer the data to another texture.

There are suggestions on the Internet to use glCopyTexImage2D. But after I tried it, I found that the texture was copied and pre-multiplied again, causing the translucent part to render abnormally.

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:sourceCtx];
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, sourceFbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, w, h, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:targetCtx];
```

The pixels read from openGL are premultiplied, so does the data passed in through the glTexImage2D/glCopyTexImage2D method have to be unpremultiplied?

Comment: What about [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml)?

Comment: *"then de-premultiply (because the data in the frame buffer is pre-multiplied)"* - If the texture is a framebuffer attachment, it is not "de-premultiply". The texture is the buffer into which the frame buffer writes its data.

Comment: I am using openGL ES 2.0, glBlitFramebuffer is not supported.

Comment: Are you trying to port something from OpenGL to OpenGLES? That is, from PC to mobile?